# JS error infinite loop in leetcode easy question

Tags: javascript

I have this error in a [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-title/). The post on the discussion section is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-title/discuss/1916152/Error-with-more-than-one-char-solution-in-JS). I am doing it in JS but I got an error when executing with some questions

**Description:**

Given an integer columnNumber, return its corresponding column title as it appears in an Excel sheet.

For example:

```
A -> 1
B -> 2
C -> 3
...
Z -> 26
AA -> 27
AB -> 28 
...
```

**My solution:**

```
/**
 * @param {number} columnNumber
 * @return {string}
 */
var convertToTitle = function(columnNumber) {
   
    const alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
   
    var name = "";
    while (columnNumber > 0) {
        name = name.concat(alphabet[columnNumber%26 - 1]);
        columnNumber = columnNumber - columnNumber%26;
    }
    return(name);
};
```

When I call the function with `colNumber` < 26 it works like a charm, but why does the code crash when I execute it with a greater number? I think it is an infinite loop but I am not sure.

Comment: The code crashes (meaning you get an error - if so, which one?), or it's an infinite loop (the code just hangs and the app becomes unresponsive)? These are two different things

Comment: The core-idea (of using `%` to find the remainder) is appropriate. Rather than go for a `while` loop, to determine how many `A`'s will precede the character corresponding to the remainder - why not use integer-division. **SPOILER ALERT** A one-liner that you may try / test / share-feedback: ``const getColName = num => (`${[...Array(Math.floor((num - 1) / 26)).fill('A')].join('')}${String.fromCharCode(((num - 1) % 26) + 'A'.charCodeAt(0))}`);``

Answer (score 2):

You can try to debug on the paper, it will help you a lot.

Imagine you have an input = 27

as first loop it will be

```
while (columnNumber > 0) {
    name = name.concat(alphabet[columnNumber %26 - 1]); # 
    columnNumber = 27- 27%26; 
  # columnNumber = 27 - 1 , new columnNumber  will be 26
}
```

seems like it works perfectly but what happens when you run
the second loop with the new columnNumber  value = 26

```
while (columnNumber > 0) {
    name = name.concat(alphabet[columnNumber %26 - 1]); # 
    columnNumber = columnNumber - columnNumber %26; 
  # columnNumber = 26 - 26%26 , 26 mod 26 = 0
  # then you will get you inf loop 26 - 0
}
```

Comment: u just need to change the algorithme calcule it like h , m , s

Comment: you are right thanks. I have also noticed that the algorithm is not correct

Answer (score -1):

Nice exercise! Quick and dirty code:

```
function convertToTitle(columnNumber) {
    columnNumber -= 1;
    let name = "";
    let alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    while (columnNumber >= 0) {
        if (columnNumber > alphabet.length - 1) {
            name = name.concat(alphabet[Math.floor(columnNumber / 25) - 1]);
            columnNumber -= Math.floor(columnNumber / 25) * 25;
            columnNumber -= 1;
        } else {
            name = name.concat(alphabet[columnNumber]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Edit:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5em4p.png)

Explenation:
1 -> A, but an Array starts at index 0, so `columnNumber -= 1`
27 -> AB, get the base (A) by dividing with 25 (`alphabet.length - 1`) and the rest of the division
If columnNumber is `<26` (u know, index starts at 0) we can get the char directly.

A bit cleaner way would be the usage of `String.charAt(index)`

```
const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
alphabet.charAt(0); // returns char at 0 -> A
```

Comment: i have tested your code but it needs some tuning. I think the correct way would be dividing it by 26 and then deleting one for the array index. I have tested your code and i have some testcases incorrect. I have also made some small modificatinos but is istill not passing the tests. I found the original error that was the infinite loop, now is just designing a good algorithim. Thanks!